# SAS email to an outlook mailing list

Tags: sas

I am trying to send emails in SAS and want to start mailing to enterprise mailing lists instead of hard-coding individual emails the SAS code.  Is this possible?  None of my emails actually make it to the mailing list when I have done tests.

Answer (score 0):

If your company is similar to 99% of the companies I have seen (as a consultant), you will have an MS Exchange server (Active Directory/LDAP) handling your email. I have only ever seen 1 instance of someone using a non-MS LDAP environment. If so, you need to connect to AD/LDAP from SAS. See this blog post I wrote 10 years ago (still works the same): https://savian.blogspot.com/2012/03/sas-and-ldap.html. You can find others out there as well. You need to access the AD mailing lists or just use the generic ones set up in AD (ex. ITStaff@abc.com).

I never use SAS for stuff like emails. I set up a web service in C# and push to it. C# and AD go together easily and the mailing clients are much, much better (ex. FluentEMail). A web service can stand up in no time. See YT for .NET 6 Kestrel WebAPI. YMMV.